# Broken images, jumbotron don't show background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea why images don't show properly when I upload code to the server...
Locally it works.

Image from jumbotron (with absolute path):

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://rabatowe.pl/zdjecia/jumbotron/dalia.jpg');
  height: 550px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

And images from flexslider (with relative path):

```
<div id="container" class="cf">
        <div id="main" role="main">
          <section class="slider">
            <div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">

                    <li data-thumb="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/1.jpg">
                    <img src="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/1.jpg" />
                    </li>                       
                    <li data-thumb="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/3.jpg">
                    <img src="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/3.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li data-thumb="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/4.jpg">
                    <img src="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/4.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li data-thumb="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/5.jpg">
                    <img src="../zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/5.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                      </section>
                         </div>
                    </div></div>
```

Click: [site with these problems](http://rabatowe.pl/html/oferta.html)

1. index.html
2. zdjecia // pictures

    2.2 kwiaty // flowers

   - aksamitka_drobno ->
     1.jpg
     2.jpg
     3.jpg
   - aksamitka_wielko ->
     1.jpg
     2.jpg
     3.jpg
   - jumbotron -> dalia.jpg
3. css

Comment: Look at your console. It shows that you're not pointing your images to the right path. You jumbotron absolute path is show a 404 page.

Comment: is this you image path `http://rabatowe.pl/zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/1.jpg`

Comment: http://rabatowe.pl/zdjecia/kwiaty/aksamitka_drobno/1.jpg this gives me 404 file not found, did you correctly upload those folders to your host?
Also, by overlooking here real fast on your HTML i can't find any element assigned to jumbotron class, maybe im too overhasty.

Comment: 1. Check paths. 2. Check permissions

Comment: check your image path.. check your folder structure..

Comment: update found the jumbotron, its using a relative path that links to http://rabatowe.pl/zdjecia/jumbotron/pompony.jpg, which is also a 404.

Comment: Sorry, I have so bad Internet connection I can bearly connect to my server. Here's complete site structure: http://i.imgur.com/pV8VN0M.png

Answer (score 0):

"http://rabatowe.pl/zdjecia/jumbotron/dalia.jpg" doesn't exist... (tries to just enter this url)
also i get a lot of errors when entering the website
when entering the site i get those errors

maybe you should check your permissions or if the urls are correct

good luck mate!